# calculate week number by changing the start of week in r

Tags: r, data.table, lubridate, dayofweek, week-number

I'm trying to count the week number by shifting the start of the week from day 7 (in lubridate, the default Sunday = 7) to day 5 (Friday) *Note: If you get the day of week numbers with* `wday` *function from lubridate, it will return 1 for Sunday and 6 for Friday, but in order to get my week counter to start on Friday, its the day index -1*.

That being said, I've written a function that continues to throw an error.

```
dates <- seq.Date(ymd(20150101), ymd(20171231), by = 1)

friday_week <- function(dates) {

  require(lubridate)
  require(data.table)
  require(dplyr)

dates = if(is.Date(dates) == F) {

 stop("this must be a date object")

}

date_yr = lubridate::year(dates)

wk_days = lubridate::wday(dates, week_start = 5)

date_df = data.frame(date_yr, wk_days) %>% data.table()

date_df[ , fri_wk := ifelse(cumsum(wk_days == 1) < 53, cumsum(wk_days == 1) 
+ 1, cumsum(wk_days == 1)), by = date_yr]

return(date_df$fri_wk)


}
```

Running it with dates, I get this message:

```
Error in as.POSIXlt.default(x, tz = tz(x)) : 
do not know how to convert 'x' to class “POSIXlt”
```

But when I run the lines of code within the function line by line outside of the function, it produces exactly what I want.

I'm lost.

Comment: You haven't defined the direction of the "shift". Should it be based on the configuration of days-of-the-week at the beginning of the year, and if so then define the algorithm.

Comment: lol, what is this: `date_df = data.frame(date_yr, wk_days) %>% data.table()`?

Comment: To the close voter: this is a good debugging question. It's fully reproducible, we know the desired behavior. The bug is that the result of an `if` statement was assigned to a variable later used as an argument. That is not a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
dates = if(is.Date(dates) == F) {

    stop("this must be a date object")

  }
```

to:

```
 if(is.Date(dates) == F) {

    stop("this must be a date object")

  }
```

At the moment when you call `lubridate::year(dates)`, `dates` is `NULL`. Inside the `lubridate::year()` function, it's trying to convert `NULL` to `POSIX.lt`

```
x <- NULL
as.POSIXlt(x)
# Error in as.POSIXlt.default(x) : 
#   do not know how to convert 'x' to class “POSIXlt”
```

Learn how to use `debug()` and the browser. It will help you find your bugs :)

Comment: Thank you!  I was just checking out the debug tool...still don't quite have it but I'm on the right track.  Gracias!

Comment: @ToddShannon it takes a bit to get the hang of it, but once you do, it's very helpful! I usually use `n` to step over function calls until I find the line in particular that throws the error, then call it again, switching from `n` to `s` to step into the function call if I want to drill down further. Just remember, you can examine the environment or the value of any variable at any point. In RStudio, the environment window even lists it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your error should be in the

```
dates = if(is.Date(dates) == F) {
stop("this must be a date object")
}
```

remove the `dates =`  part.